# How to pass Type as a Parameter to Method

Tags: c#, methods, types

Im new to C# however im running into an issue when trying to pass the `TableOne` type class into a method and use within the method itself.

Class:

```cs
    public class TableOne
    {
        public List<string> CaseID { get; set; }
        public List<string> Owner { get; set; }
        public List<string> Assignee { get; set; }
        public List<string> Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

Method:

```cs
public static string ComposeHtmlTable<T>(Type classType, IList<T> table)
{
    List<classType> test = table.Cast<classType>().ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(test[0].CaseID[0]); // trying to access data

    return "test";
}
```

How the method is being called:

```cs
ComposeHtmlTable<TableOne>(typeof(TableOne), data.TableOne);
```

Error im receiving:

```
'classType' is a variable but is used like a type.
```

The reason why its imperative that the method uses the parameter type is because there might be multiple types i.e. `TableTwo` or `TableThree` that I might pass into that method.

Any ideas on how I can tackle this?

TIA

Comment: Pass it as a _generic type parameter_ in angle-brackets. You don't need `Type` at all.

Comment: Thanks @Dai, are you able to show how I could do that? I've tried to do a generic type before but I wasn't able to access the List properties

Comment: I just bothered to look at your code now and the _real_ problem is that your `ComposeHtmlTable` method has a bad design. Generic methods (i.e. methods with _generic-type-parameters_) should not be concerned with details of their type-arguments: so your `ComposeHtmlTable` method _should not_ be attempting to look at `test[0].CaseID[0]` in the first place. I don't know why you're doing that in the first place, really - but I don't think you should be using generics here.

Comment: @ayushlal   You want to use generic that have multiple classes,right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965580/c-sharp-generics-syntax-for-multiple-type-parameter-constraints

Comment: Thanks @Dai. The reason for that is im trying to create a method that will iterate over the given ```List``` with a given Type and return the HTML output of the iteration

Comment: @ayushlal That's not a problem for which generics are a suitable solution. It sounds like you need to use good ol' fashioned OOP design-patterns for serialization instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733317/are-there-any-patterns-for-serializing-and-deserializing-object-hierarchies-in-v

Comment: @ayushlal Also, a "table" is generally understood to be a _set-of-tuples_ (or just a "list-of-rows"), but your `TableOne` class is a "_tuple-of-lists-of-strings_", which is _not_ a table.

Comment: Use [where clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) with `IList` or `IList<U>` with either second generic or fixed type (containing `CaseID`).

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at `classType` and `T`:

```
public static string ComposeHtmlTable<T>(Type classType, IList<T> table)
{
    List<classType> test = table.Cast<classType>().ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(test[0].CaseID[0]); // trying to access data

    return "test";
}
```

Can they be some *arbitrary types*, say `T == int` and `classType == StringBuider`?
Definitely not. As I can see, both `classType` and `T` should be inherited from `TableOne`.
Let's .net know it:

```
public static string ComposeHtmlTable<C, T>(IList<T> table) 
  where C : TableOne
  where T : TableOne 
{...}
```

Time to add some details:

- we don't want `IList<T> table` as an argument, `IEnumerable<T> table` is enough (and we will be able to pass not only lists, by, say, arrays)
- the method is declares as `public`, any input is possible; so we have to validate input arguments
- what if `test` is empty (i.e. it doesn't have any items?). We can't obtain `test[0].CaseID[0]` in this case.

```
public static string ComposeHtmlTable<C, T>(IEnumerable<T> table) 
  where C : TableOne
  where T : TableOne 
{
    if (table is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(table));  

    List<C> test = table.Cast<C>().ToList();

    if (test.Count > 0 && test[0] != null && test[0].CaseID.Count > 0)
        Console.WriteLine(test[0].CaseID[0]); // trying to access data  
    else
        Console.WriteLine("test is empty");

   return "test"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line of code `List<classType> test = table.Cast<classType>().ToList();`
`List<classType>` and `Cast<classType>` is invalid syntax.
`List<T>` is acceptable.

Type arguments in c# are sent separately to variables.
You've already supplied the type argument T to the generic method.
So use `List<T>` and `Cast<T>` instead.

Hence passing in classType as a variable is redundant.
Even if you needed to do a switch expression on the the type of elements supplied you can switch on `typeof(T)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried to do ```List<T> & Cast<T>``` however I get the following error ```'T' does not contain a definition for 'CaseID' and no accessible extension method 'CaseID' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?```

Comment: That's another problem: you should work out how to cast between the two types...

Answer (score 0):

As @Dai suggest, you could replace the `classType` parameter by an generic type parameter:

```
static List<T1> ComposeHtmlTable<T1,T2>(IList<T2> table)
{        
    List<T1> test = table.Cast<T1>().ToList();
    return test;
}
```

PS: I changed your method to return the new List, since I presume that's what you wanted to achieve...

And call it like:

`ComposeHtmlTable<TableOne,TableOne>(data.TableOne);`

If the two generic types will always be the same you can rteduce the method to:

```
static List<T> ComposeHtmlTable<T>(IList<T> table)
{
    return (List<T>) table.Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

and call it like:

`ComposeHtmlTable<TableOne>(data.TableOne);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it out shortly. Just for my my knowledge what is the purpose for ```<TableOne, TableOne>``` when calling the method?

Comment: No luck... ```Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T2>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T1>```

Comment: @ayushlal: You are passing the two generic types: one for the type of the elements in the returned List and one to specify what kind of IList you will be passing in. 
If in your application those two will always be the same, you can just stick to one generic Type parameter. I added this to the answer. If you feel the answer is helpfull please upvote it. If it is the right answer to your question, please mark it as correct?

Comment: Of course: two be able to use the 'Cast' operator, there should be a cast defined between your two types...

Comment: Thanks for your help, another quick one. It seems that I cannot access the Properties in the list i.e. ```test[0].CaseID[0])```, I get the following error: ```'T' does not contain a definition for 'CaseID' and no accessible extension method 'CaseID' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?```

Comment: Inside your generic method the compiler has no knowledge of the properties of the type being passed. So you cannot use them.
For debugging purposes: put that statement right after the call to `ComposeHtmlTable`.